# Is celebrating the secular new year forbidden or problematic since it is based around a calendar relating to Jesus' birth?

Tags: avodah-zarah, sin, non-jewish-holidays, secular-culture

The secular calendar in most countries is based around the BC/AD system. This calendar is derived from the Julian and Gregorian calendar traditions which mark the birth of Jesus as a focal point for measuring time.

***All events before his birth being BC and afterward are AD. In this design, the world quite literally revolves around Jesus.***

As such, can't it be argued that the celebration of the secular New Year isn't really secular? What I mean is a New Years Eve party is really celebrating and acknowledging a calendar system developed around the idol worship of Jesus.

Has this issue ever been discussed by Rabbinical authorities at any point?

Comment: It has been discussed by rabbinical authorities all the way back in the Mishna which lists New Year as an idolatrous holiday https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Avodah_Zarah.1.3

Comment: 1 January as New Year's Day started with the Romans, even before Julius Caesar's reforms which are now called the Julian Calendar, and as such was not Christian - though clearly was associated with the Roman god Janus.

Comment: In France it was called the holiday of the circumcision because he was born in the 25 and circumcised in the 1.1

Comment: "_As such, can't it be argued that the celebration of the secular New Year isn't really secular?_ ..." R. [Shlomo Aviner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Aviner) seems to [make that argument](http://shlomo-aviner.net/index.php?title=%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9A_%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%99-%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99_(%D7%A9%D7%95%22%D7%AA)).

Comment: I don't understand your derivation of AC/BC to new year's day. The two have nothing to do with each other. As well, as others pointed out, January 1 as new year's predated Christianity.

Comment: @DoubleAA which holiday in that Mishnah is new year's? Who says it's January 1?

Comment: @robev Calendia (same root as Calendar). See the meforshim there like Yachin, or Jastrow https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%A7%D6%B8%D7%9C%D6%B4%D7%A0%D6%B0%D7%93%D6%B7%D6%BC%D7%A1?lang=bi I wasn't aware this was controversial.